# Can a computer send UDP datagram to itself without a router?

Tags: networking, udp

I want to send and receive UDP datagrams on a single computer for testing purposes. I can do it when a router is connected.

What if there is no router and no connection? Is there a trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send datagrams to [localhost address `127.0.0.1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and listen for datagrams on this address.